# How to get value from cell with query and importrange functions in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

A1 cell has `1`. And I try use value from this cell through:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxx/edit?usp=sharing"; "Sheet1!A:P");       
     "select * where Col1='"&A1&"'"; -1 )
```

But I can't use information from `A1` cell. I have nothing result.
But, if I change code **Col1='"&A1&"'** to **Col1=1** it works.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxx/edit?usp=sharing"; "Sheet1!A:P");       
         "select * where Col1=1"; -1 )
```

But I need that query function use value from `A1` cell.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query we **only use single quotes when the value is text**  like `klm`

```
"where Col1=' "&A1&" ' "
```

**With numbers we do NOT use single quotes**.
It looks like the value in your `A1` cell is the number `1`
So your query should be

```
"where Col1="&A1&" "
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. 
Please remember that you can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because your formula sets the third parameter as `-1` which means that the column headers should be guessed. Remove this parameter or set it to `0`, but, there is a simpler way to get the value of A1:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxx/edit?usp=sharing"; "Sheet1!A1")
```