# How to use query with a criteria where Col1 is equal to a value in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets-query

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kYkfBoDsJR-sBo5J52lJTXKa-EXoFYPgVPnrRGvOx5A/edit?usp=sharing

`=query(Importrange("1kYkfBoDsJR-sBo5J52lJTXKa-EXoFYPgVPnrRGvOx5A","LastRevision!A5:Y"),"Select * where Col3 = '"&B28&"'",1)`
What is wrong with '"&B28&"' instead of just typing the number.
Why its showing error..
'"&B28&"' contains a number which I want to match with the reference column. If I just type the number it works well, but referring to the cell that has the number doesn't work.

Comment: [This is the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/150617/117311) you are looking for.

Comment: For me it didn't work probably because the cell contains this
`='CASES LIST'!C6` and C6 is the number of day in another sheet and its date in "d" format

Comment: Select *  Where Col3= date ' "&TEXT('CASES LIST'!C6,"d")&" ' ",0) where 'Cases List'C6 is Date in "dd-mm-yyyy". And I need the "d" only

Comment: Ok. I got it. first I have to convert that into a text in another cell
`=TEXT('CASES LIST'!C6,"D")` then use this cell as reference.. Thanks

Comment: Good work Hassan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got it. first I have to convert that into a text in another cell =TEXT('CASES LIST'!C6,"D") then use this cell as reference.. Thanks